# JS if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an set of radiobuttons, the number can be anything from 1 to 10 or even more.

The buttons are created with:

```
 <div class="form-group btn-group has-feedback" id="div_add_bedrijf" data-toggle="buttons">';
    foreach ($_SESSION['bedrijf'] as $value)
    {
        echo '<label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" id="add_bedrijf" name="add_bedrijf" value="'.$value.'" onclick="validate_add()" onmousemove="validate_add()"><img src="images/logo_'.$value.'_small.png" height="30"></label>';
    }
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="add_bedrijf_status">
</div>
```

No I would like an form validation to check if any option is chosen before the form is send.
I have written the JS below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_add()
{
    // bedrijf
    if(document.getElementById('add_bedrijf').checked) { document.getElementById('div_bedrijf').className = "form-group has-warning has-feedback"; document.getElementById('add_bedrijf_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else
    { document.getElementById('div_add_bedrijf').className = "form-group has-success has-feedback"; document.getElementById('add_bedrijf_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }
}
</script>
```

The radio buttons are generated without any problems.
The JS script is not working as I want. Even if none of the buttons is checked the script is running the else statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can see your are creating the elements within a **php** `foreach`, you should be sure this doesn't result in multiple elements having the same `id` as `id`'s should be unique.

Comment: OK, I might agree on that,  but how to check this number of different ID's in JS then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would make sure every radio button has an unique id, changing your PHP code to the following:

```
<div class="form-group btn-group has-feedback" id="div_add_company" data-toggle="buttons">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['company'] as $value)
    {
        ?>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary" for="add_company_<?php echo $i;?>">
            <input type="radio" id="add_company_<?php echo $i;?>" name="add_company" value="<?php echo $value;?>" onclick="validate_add()" onblur="validate_add()" />
            <img src="images/logo_<?php echo $value;?>_small.png" alt="<?php echo $value;?>" height="30"/>
        </label>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="add_company_status"></span>
</div>
```

after that I would update the Javascript to this:

```
function validate_add() {
        // Parent div of all buttons
        let div_add_company = document.getElementById('div_add_company');
        // Status div
        let add_company_status = document.getElementById('add_company_status');
        // A list with all the inputs that start the with id "add_company_"
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="add_company_"]');
        for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            let element = elements[i];
            // If the element is checked
            if(element.checked) {
                // Remove the warning
                div_add_company.classList.remove('has-warning');
                // Add success
                div_add_company.classList.add('has-success');
                // Remove the warning icon
                add_company_status.classList.remove('glyphicon-warning-sign');
                // Add the success icon
                add_company_status.classList.add('glyphicon-ok');
                // We found one was selected, so exit the loop
                return;
            } else {
                // Remove the success
                div_add_company.classList.remove('has-success');
                // Add the warning
                div_add_company.classList.add('has-warning');
                // Remove the success icon
                add_company_status.classList.remove('glyphicon-ok');
                // Add the warning icon
                add_company_status.classList.add('glyphicon-warning-sign');

            }
        }
    }
```

I also suggest that you don't mix Dutch with English in your code. try to keep everything in English.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Jeffrey!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
if(document.getElementById('add_bedrijf').checked) { document.getElementById('div_bedrijf').className = "form-group has-warning has-feedback"; document.getElementById('add_bedrijf_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
```

Try changing `document.getElementById('div_bedrijf').className` to `document.getElementById('div_add_bedrijf').className` ; )

Comment: The icon in that div is correct, I think the error is in 'if(document.getElementById('add_bedrijf').checked)'

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same id on all of the inputs, this will cause your getElementById to check always the same element, no matter how many are there.

You have to somehow differentiate your inputs, or just pass context of an element to a function like `validate_add.call(this)`. That way you can focus on each element without having to use dom function to find the elements again.

In the function then you would have something like:

```
function validate_add(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
    element.className = "form-group has-warning has-feedback";
    document.getElementById('add_bedrijf_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('div_add_bedrijf').className = "form-group has-success has-feedback";
    document.getElementById('add_bedrijf_status').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback";
  }
}
```

Truth be told with vanilla javascript you would have hard time with this parent/sibling DOM manipulation, if you have access to jQuery it is one of its core features...

OR

You could add different id's or data-attributes to each input. And access them like that.

i.e.

input-1
input-2
input-3 ...

Comment: input-1 input-2 input-3 . >> OK >> but I don't know how many there are at the present time, so how check all existing in JS?

Comment: Well, your PHP knows it, so you create different ID's it in the php, but I recommend you to use function that I wrote you.